# Send AudioBuffer to Speaker

Tags: javascript, websocket, audiocontext, audio-worklet

Here's what I want to do:

1. Send microphone audio to AudioWorketProcessor (works)
2. Send results from AudioWorkletProcessor to a server using WebSockets (works)
3. Receive back the data over WebSockets (works)
4. Send data to the computer's speakers (how to do it?)

Everything works except I don't know how to implement #4. Here's what I have, some things simplified to keep focus on the problem:

//1. The code to set up the audio context. Connects the microphone to the worklet

```
    const audioContext = new AudioContext({ sampleRate: 8000 });
    audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('/common/recorderworkletprocess.js').then(
        function () {
            const recorder = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'recorder-worklet');
            let constraints = { audio: true };
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
                const microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                microphone.connect(recorder);
                recorder.connect(audioContext.destination);
            });
        }
    );
```

//2. The AudioWorkletProcessor. Sends audio to the WebSocket, which sends it to the server as binary:

```
  class RecorderWorkletProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
     constructor() {
        super();
     }
     process(inputs) {
        const inputChannel = inputs[0][0];  //inputChannel Float32Array(128)
        socket.send(inputChannel);  // sent as byte[512]
        return true;
     }
  }
  registerProcessor('recorder-worklet', RecorderWorkletProcessor);
```

//3 and 4. Finally, the server sends back the data exactly as it was received. The WebSocket converts it to ArrayBuffer(512). Here I want to do whatever it takes to output it to the computer's speaker as audio:

```
socket.messageReceived = function (evt) {
// evt.data contains an ArrayBuffer with length of 512
// I want this to be played on the computer's speakers. How to do this?
  }
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey I'm trying to reproduce a similar situation, but am stuck on getting access to the WebSocket in the AudioWorkletProcessor. In your code you have 

    process(inputs) {
        const inputChannel = inputs[0][0];  //inputChannel Float32Array(128)
        socket.send(inputChannel);  // sent as byte[512]
        return true;
     }

How were you able to get access to socket.send? I keep getting the error that WebSocket is not defined whenever I try to start a new instance of WebSocket from within the AudioWorkletProcessor class.

Comment: It's just a standard WebSocket connection. Just get a connection and make sure it is in scope.

Comment: The issue I'm having is getting the WebSocket connection within the scope of the AudioWorkletProcessor. I keep receiving the error of WebSocket is not defined at AudioWorkletProcessor.process if I try to define it within the AudioWorkletProcessor class, or if I try to pass a WebSocket connection using the options.processorOptions, it says it could not be cloned. If you don't mind me asking, would you be able to show the code you used to get a websocket working in your AudioWorkletProcessor? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I believe I can answer my question. This is not robust but it provides what I needed to know.

```
  socket.messageReceived = function (evt) {
     // evt.data contains an ArrayBuffer with length of 512
     // I want this to be played on the computer's speakers. How to do this?
     let fArr = new Float32Array(evt.data);
     let.buf = audioContext.createBuffer(1, 128, 8000);
     buf.copyToChannel(fArr, 0);
     let player = audioContext.createBufferSource();
     player.buffer = buf;
     player.connect(audioContext.destination);    
     player.start(0);
  }
```

Comment: I tried your example and I have an issue. Voice is robotic. Did you encouter this issue too? I feel like it has something to do with buffer. I tried to play it directly from worklet and there was no difference from playing it from socket.

Comment: No, I didn't experience that.